# Issue with getting data from array

Tags: php, arrays

Whenever I seek to show the contents of an array based on data from an SQL database, the output always is prefixed with the word "Array". It doesn't matter whether I use echo, print_r(), var_dump() or otherwise. Code below. Any ideas greatly received!

```
$prefix1 = ''; 
$tasks = array($product, $service, $order, $social, $competition, $dataOther);
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    if ($task == '') {
        unset($task);
    } else {
        $tasks .= $prefix1 . '' . $task . '';
        $prefix1 = ', ';
    }
} 
echo $tasks;
```

Output - "Array" followed by the contents of $tasks

**Edit:** I cannot use `implode(', ', $tasks)` because each of the inputs (i.e. `$product`, `$service` etc.) could be blank and therefore the outcome would be ",," in places.

Hope that's clearer.

Comment: What do you want to do ??`$tasks .= $prefix1 . '' . $task . '';`

Comment: You are overwriting your array in the loop, casting it to a string when you add a string to it. You should use a different name.

Comment: `$tasks` is an array or at least it was before you ran this code on it. You cannot `echo` an array

Comment: You cannot add to an array using `.=`

Comment: Basically this code makes very little sence! Fixing it would require more information about what your actual intent was!

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I'll clarify below

Comment: @LegalDan See my edit. By the way, I have also edited your question to get the original part back so that the comments and my answer will keep making sense.

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting your array in the loop, casting it to a string when you add a string to it. You should use a different name for the string you are building.

Although you don't really need a loop for this, you can replace your code with just:

```
$tasks = array($product, $service, $order, $social, $competition, $dataOther);
echo implode(', ', $tasks);
```

**Edit:** Based on your edit - that the variables can be blank - you can filter the empty values before you `implode`: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) without a callback function / second parameter removes empty values:

```
$tasks = array($product, $service, $order, $social, $competition, $dataOther);
echo implode(', ', array_filter($tasks));
```

Note that this will also filter strings like `0` so if that is not what you want, you would have to add a callback function that meets your requirements.